# UNIX man command to find list of man sections

Tags: linux, unix, manpage

I'm working on a lab that is supposed to help us better navigate the command line on a Linux system, but I'm getting stuck on man pages.

We are supposed to use the man command to find a list of the man page sections, adn I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried entering

```
man man
```

but that doesn't give me any information on the individual sections. I've also tried looking on Google to find what command I should use, but no luck there either.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.december.com/unix/ref/mansec.html

Comment: Btw, `man man` does give a list of the sections in the “DESCRIPTION” paragraph.

Comment: Here's what I get in the Description paragraph when I enter the man man command: 
DESCRIPTION
       man formats and displays the on-line manual pages.  If you specify sec-
       tion, man only looks in that section of the manual.  name  is  normally
       the  name of the manual page, which is typically the name of a command,
       function, or file.  However, if name contains  a  slash  (/)  then  man
       interprets  it  as a file specification, so that you can do man ./foo.5
       or even man /cd/foo/bar.1.gz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apropos -r '.*'
```

This will list all manual pages. A script to chop this up into lists by section is a follow-up homework assignment.