# dumpsys grep options "-i"

Tags: android, python, windows, grep

I tried to get the brightness level of android device using dumpsys.
"**dumpsys power | grep -i  mScreenBrightness=**"
which returns the required output .

What does "-i" resembles here 
where as "**dumpsys power | grep mScreenBrightness=**" .. also returns same value.

Comment: Was that really more convenient than typing `man grep` and searching for `-i`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNIX man command to find list of man sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879960/unix-man-command-to-find-list-of-man-sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -i` stands for case insensitive

Comment: Lino .. Thanks for your reply .. got it .